# How to listen to StatefulWidget variable changes flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My App has a StatefulWidget variable in a single file and calls it on all pages, but all pages did not listen to changes if the variable"widget" changed on one page.

Comment: Stateful widgets do not store state globally across your application. Each instance has its own state. If you want to have your state stored in a single place to use in several different places, you might want to look into provider: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: the widget changed but after refreshing the page-push another page then return to it-. I looked at the provider package but I did understand how to use it. please can you give me an example?

Comment: There are probably literally a hundred different tutorials on how to use `provider`, and likewise dozens of tutorials on the package that replaced it, `riverpod`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ValueNotifier to listen the change.

Comment: Answers like this can't just be one sentence. You need to include a code example.